# Iterate through nested array objects with Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, pug

I want to render this data on my view with Jade. This is returned from the QPX api. I have data structured like this.

```
{ 
  kind: 'qpxExpress#tripsSearch',
  trips: { 
    kind: 'qpxexpress#tripOptions',
    requestId: 'OqaX52F0Z433IbMlh0PNr6',
    data: {
      kind: 'qpxexpress#data',
      airport: [Object],
      city: [Object],
      aircraft: [Object],
      tax: [Object],
      carrier: [Object]
    },
    tripOption: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  }
}
```

How do I access the nested object array in tripOption using Jade? I can't seem to work it out. This is my Jade template:

```
block content
  .ui
    for data in result
      .ui_box
        .ui_box__inner
          .event
            span #{data.tripOption[0].slice[0]}
```

This is the error I receive from Jade

`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Router

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  api.apiGet(function (data) {
    console.log(data) 
    res.render('index', {result: data})
  })
})
```

Comment: how does your route handler look like when passing the data to your view? There is a disconnect between the data and the view atm without that knowledge.

Comment: I have updated the question with the route

Comment: `#{data.tripOption[0].slice[0]}` the `[ ]` after slice bothers me...

Comment: That's from the API documentation but I have tried to remove it already and I still receive the error.

Comment: `.slice()` is an array method on javascript not jade. anyway, have you tried `#{data.trips.tripOption[0]}`? notice the `trips` between data and tripOption.

Comment: oh wait, you're passing in an object. You shouldn't need to loop that early. just access the data directly until you reach `tripOption` then iterate.

Comment: Are you able to provide a small example of that? Just stuck getting my head around it

Comment: you might have to rearrange your elements but your for loop might look like this: `for data in result.trips.tripOption`, then data should be the objects found at `tripOption`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is iterating on an object, which won't work. This isn't the usual `for..in` loop in native [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

The code below modifies the router a little and passes the data (`tripOptions`) to the view in a more direct way. First the Jade template:

```
block content
  .ui
    for data in tripOptions
      .ui_box
        .ui_box__inner
          .event
            span #{data.someProp}
```

new router with the tripOption data made available to the view as `tripOptions` (plural):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  api.apiGet(function (data) {
    console.log(data) 
    res.render('index', {
      tripOptions: data.trips.tripOption
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Okay this is great but now I'm being thrown another error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. It's on this line `for data in tripOptions`

Comment: yeah seems like tripOptions isn't pointing to an array. Maybe `console.log(data)`  before you call `res.render` and see if you can access the data sowly, e.g. trying `console.log(data.trips)` then drilling deeper one property at a time.

Comment: Thanks, got there!